# SQL Query pivoting or grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have an issue in making a SQL query to sort out a datatable and dont know how to approach it. That is, i have a datatable that looks like this:

[image]

And i would like to query it like this:

[image]

For retrieving the initial datatable i'm using following query:

```
SELECT top 100 replace(convert(varchar, db1.Create_On,101),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar, db1.Create_On,108),':','') as 'Creation_Date', db1.PSP, db1.Create_on, db1.Create_by, db1.Language, db1.Name, db1.FirstName, db2.*
from db1 INNER JOIN
     db2
     ON (db1.IB_H_Id = db2.IB_H_Id) AND (db1.Create_on = db2.Create_on) AND (db1.Create_by = db2.Create_by)
WHERE (((db1.IB_H_Id)='CLA_052') AND ((db1.SendMail) Like '') AND ((db2.Answer_Char) = 'Email') OR ((db2.Answer_Char) = 'Card'))
order by [Creation_Date];
```

Now i don't know how to approach it whether with group by or pivot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh: im using SQL Server Native Client 11.0 if that is what you mean. Regarding second question, i tried to paste the table but i couldn't

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select column1,
       max(case when column2 = 1 then column3 end) as col2_1,
       max(case when column2 = 2 then column3 end) as col2_2,
       max(case when column2 = 3 then column3 end) as col2_3
from t
group by column1;
```

Comment: thank for this, i applied it and got an error: The column 'Create_on' was specified multiple times for 't'. Indeed this column appears on both datatables, I tried to specifically specify it for certain datatable but couldn't yet solve this

Comment: @ChenChela . . . Your sample data doesn't even have a column called `created_on`.  Just list the columns you need in the CTE.